# CloneNotSupportedException even when implementing Cloneable

Tags: java, java-7

Why does the following code throw CloneNotSupportedException in JDK7 but **NOT in JDK6**?

```
public class DemoThread extends Thread implements Cloneable {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoThread t = new DemoThread();
        t.cloned();
    }

    public DemoThread cloned()
    {
        try {
            return (DemoThread) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Apparently, method was changed in accordance with the following justification in javadocs: `Throws CloneNotSupportedException as a Thread can not be meaningfully cloned.`

Comment: would help if you included the stack trace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's Thread's implementation of `clone()` in SE 7

```
/**
 * Throws CloneNotSupportedException as a Thread can not be meaningfully
 * cloned. Construct a new Thread instead.
 *
 * @throws  CloneNotSupportedException
 *          always
 */
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
}
```

Threads were never designed to be cloned. Doing some reading sparked off one of the comments I found this summed it up quite well : ["But we either 
have to disallow cloning or give it meaningful semantics - and the 
latter isn't going to happen."](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-August/004746.html) -- David Holmes

Comment: We can look into source code to see this. The question is why wasn't it implemented in such a way in earlier versions of JDK.

Comment: Probably because they made a design error by making Thread implement Cloneable, and fixed this design error in JDK7.

Comment: Found something related - http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=23cced47-ccdb-460d-acc9-ce16154ab6a5

Answer (score 3):

This does not work because threads cannot be cloned. Line 16 of your code tries to clone the superclass(Thread) which does not implement the interface Cloneable. Besides cloning a thread is not a good idea at all. You need to create a new thread. That is the only possible solution here.

Comment: Note that for a class to be Cloneable, it is not a requirement that its super class implements Cloneable too. After all Object doesn't implement Cloneable either.